# Return location of a click with respect to JFrame which is not the direct parent

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, mouselistener

I'm developing a simple Java graphics game that uses the Swing library. I have a `JFrame` that contains a `JPanel`. The panel contains buttons. The buttons have mouse listeners. I'm trying to get coordinates from my click on buttons however I need the coordinates to be with respect to the frame. When I use `e.get(x)` or `get(y)`, coordinates are relative to each button I click. I also can't use `getLocationOnScreen`.

I need something that returns the location with respect to the frame which is the grandfather container.

Comment: *"I need something that returns the location with respect to the frame which is the grandfather container."* ***..Why?*** See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [convertPoint](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#convertPoint(java.awt.Component,%20java.awt.Point,%20java.awt.Component)) method from SwingUtilities class.

In the example below i print the mouse event location relative to the button, the parent frame, and the parent frame's content pane.
However, it seems that frame's content pane could be your best try, since frame decorations and borders can make the location less accurate (on my Win10 i have about 9 "extra pixels").

Also, please follow @AndrewThompson suggestion, and tell us why you want this behaviour from your application, since there might be a better solution.

Sample code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
public class JFrameCoordinates
{
    public static void main (String [] a) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnable () {
            @Override public void run () {
                createAndShowGUI ();
            }
        });
    }
    private static void createAndShowGUI () {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Point test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane (new MainPanel ());
        frame.pack ();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo (null);
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }
}
class MainPanel extends JPanel
{
    public MainPanel () {
        super (new BorderLayout (0, 50));
        MouseAdapter listener = new MouseAdapter () {
            @Override public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent e) {
                JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource ();
                JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor (button);
                System.out.println ();
                System.out.println ("Relative to button: " + e.getPoint ());
                System.out.println ("Relative to frame: " + SwingUtilities.convertPoint (button, e.getPoint (), frame));
                System.out.println ("Relative to frame's content pane: " + SwingUtilities.convertPoint (button, e.getPoint (), frame.getContentPane ()));
            }
        };
        add (createButton ("Print Me", listener), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel (new FlowLayout (FlowLayout.CENTER, 20, 20));
        panel.add (createButton ("Print Me", listener), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add (panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setBorder (new EmptyBorder (20, 100, 20, 100));
    }
    private JButton createButton (String text, MouseAdapter listener) {
        JButton button = new JButton (text);
        button.addMouseListener (listener);
        return button;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX() - frame.getX() // X
MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY() - frame.getY() // Y
```

Those expressions will return the X and Y coordinates of the cursor, relative to the `JFrame` object.